# Get value from SpinButton to determine the number of loops

Tags: excel, vba, loops, activex

Is there any way to get the value of a cell that is connected to a SpinButton and to determine the number of times a data will be copied.

For example everytime you press the Left or Right Button it will subtract or add a value with a minimum of 1 and maximum of 1000.

This is my code so far in copying data.

```
Range("D3:D10").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial , Transpose:=True
```

The range of the cell that is associate in the SpinButton is "G7"

I want to get the value of that cell G7 to determine how many times it will copy the data from range D3 to D10.

The values is on "Sheet1". I want it to be pasted on "Sheet2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the active sheet has the G7 and range to copy

```
Range("D3:D10").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & 2 + [G7].Value).PasteSpecial , Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Edit: paste to first available cell in sheet2

-

```
Sub Copy_Trspose()
    Dim LstRw As Long, pRng As Range, cRng As Range, x
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With sh
        Set cRng = .Range("D3:D10")
        x = .Range("G7").Value
    End With

    With ws
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set pRng = .Range(.Cells(LstRw, "A"), .Cells(LstRw + x, "A"))
    End With

    cRng.Copy
    pRng.PasteSpecial , Transpose:=True

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just last one question, how can it not overwrite the previous copied data? Like it will paste to the "Sheet2" on the last blank row.

Comment: I mean I want the next data to be copied will be pasted to the last empty row in "Sheet2"

Comment: Thanks it worked but Ive been having trouble in pasting, since when it copies and paste it doesnt copy the value only but also copies the formula that is within range of the cell. I tried putting "Paste:=xlPasteValues , Transpose:=True" but it still copies the formula, any idea why it doesnt copy the value only and not include the formula?

Comment: I do not know what happened but I closed and re-opened excel and the code is working fine specially the copy and pasting! Thank you again

Comment: You did not mention the data was from a formula.